# Criar diretivas com Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

O botão deveria exibir um alert mas não aparece nada, nem erro. Qual o erro? Segue o código:

```js
  angular.module('App', [])
                    .directive('sonclick', function () {    
                         return {
                             restrict: 'A',
                             link: function(scope,element,attrs){
                                 element.bind('click',function(){       
                                     scope.$eval(attrs.sonclick);
                                 })
                             }
                         };
                    })
                    .controller('CtrlApp', function ($scope) {
                          $scope.executa = function(){
                              alert("scope");           
                          };
                    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="CtrlApp">
            <button son-click="executa()">clique aqui</button>

        </div>  
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trocando o `sonclick` por `sonClick` (atenção ao C maiúsculo) parece resolver o problema.

```js
  angular.module('App', [])
                    .directive('sonClick', function () {    
                         return {
                             restrict: 'A',
                             link: function(scope,element,attrs){
                                 element.bind('click',function(){       
                                     scope.$eval(attrs.sonClick);
                                 })
                             }
                         };
                    })
                    .controller('CtrlApp', function ($scope) {
                          $scope.executa = function(){
                              alert("scope");           
                          };
                    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="CtrlApp">
            <button son-click="executa()">clique aqui</button>

        </div>  
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Então, resumidamente `algo-algo` da view ficaria `algoAlgo` no script da diretiva? `sta-ck` > `staCk`? Estou mexendo com AngularJS e não sabia ainda que era possível criar minhas próprias diretivas.

Comment: @rrnan Isso mesmo! No HTML você pode usar atributos como `novo-item`, `novo:item` e `novo_item` que o nome da diretiva no javascript será sempre `novoItem` (camelCase).